# JQuery element created and added to sortable connected list not selectable to apply events to

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I'm not sure if I've gone about this the right way, but its what I have ended up with.
I have a master list on the LHS of the page which contains list items that can be dropped onto a number of droppable div boxes, inside the droppable div there is a ul that is sortable and connected to all the other uls on the page, so that once an item is dropped from the master list it is able to be dragged and dropped into the other uls so as to modify it's position in the connected uls.

The problem I am having is that the newly created li when dropped from the master list is not able to be selectable via jquery selectors and have events applied in a way which would be expected, I can apply events by using the id of the new item but this loses it's ability to belong to an event group, if you will, i.e context menu does not hide as it's created for each element rather than a group of elements.

I have created a fiddle page here that demonstrates a simplified set up and the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/mJLZu/54/

I think it may be a bug or an anomaly with jquery.

removing the ul.sortable code allows the newly dynamically created li to be selectable as a group using jquery.

I'm stumped. any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong. Instead of using this:

```
$('ul[class=listItem_drop] li').dblclick( function ()
```

Use this:

```
$('ul.listItem_drop li').dblclick( function ()
```

The difference here is that your first selector is looking for an element with that exact value for the class attribute, *and no other classes*. The far, far more common way to test for a class, the `.classname` selector, is what you want here.

But you ask, what other classes? Well, when you work with jQueryUI, it adds classes to keep track of some internal things. This is evident in the inspector:

[image]

(Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V57A2/).)

Comment: Thank you your awesomeness! :) One more quick question, when re-applying the events, the dblclick event is now fires twice for the original elements, how would you go about removing the original events and reapplying them so they only fire once? Thanks Again!

Comment: You'd normally do that with [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind) **but** why I'd simply *not* apply it again when things are dragged around. Or, if you really only want the events applied after dragging has occurred, don't append the event initially or use something like [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead of `.dblclick`

Comment: true, for a double click event you could just use the id, I was just using that as a simplified example. But There is a context menu that is applied to items as a group. re-applying the context menu to the group creates another instance of it. $('ul.listItem_drop li').contextMenu(menu_listItem_drop,{ theme:'vista'});    Can I use bind to add the new item to the current context menu?

Comment: I've added a new fiddle with the context menu problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/mJLZu/62/ (please ignore the contextMenu javascript at the top.)

Comment: using $('ul.listItem_drop li').unbund('contextmenu'); and then reapplying the menu does the trick, it's not as effecient as just binding the newly created control as it unbinds everything and then rebinds everything, but I don't think it is possible any other way with the way that the plug in is written as there is no reference to get to the initial menu that was bound. Cheers :)   fiddle answer : http://jsfiddle.net/Leaf369/mJLZu/77/